# gap appears in background image while zooming in

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari, background-image, zooming

I have a design with lots of round borders and I have to code with CSS2.1. So I have coded with divs giving them backgrounds with dimensions. The design looks fine when the browser window is in normal state, but when I zoom in about 2px gap appears between the divs. The problem occurs in Chrome and Safari.

What can I do to prevent the gap?

Here is the code example:

```
<div id="bigImage">
 <div id="leftRoundCorner"></div>
 <div id="middlePart"></div>
 <div id="rightRoundCorner"></div>
</div>

#bigImage
{
  height:20px;
  width:20px;
}
#leftRoundCorner
{
  height:20px;
  width:5px;
  float:left;
}
#middlePart
{
  height:20px;
  width:10px;
  float:left;
}
#rightRoundCorner
{
  height:20px;
  width:5px;
  float:right;
}
```

Comment: Browser zoom is not an exact science. There are rounding errors that break things. How browser zoom works is not standardized from browser-to-browser.

Comment: See: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-two-types-of-browser-zoom.html

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 for any rounded corners that way it will look fine zoomed in!

`-webkit-border-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
border-radius: 5px;`

and you're done!